How can I disable a "dockerfile-utils" warning in VS Code triggered by the Docker extension?
I have installed the Docker extension in VS Code. I am creating a Python cookie-cutter repository that I will use as a template to create new feature repositories. Part of the template is a Dockerfile where I want to specify a Python image (e.g. python:3.10-slim) but the image name will change based on the Python version used in the feature repository. To accommodate this, the Dockerfile in the cookie-cutter repository contains the line of code FROM python:{{cookiecutter.python_version}}-slim. Then when I am building the feature repository, the cookie cutter builds the appropriate line in the real file (e.g. FROM python:3.10-slim)
But when I include that line in the Dockerfile within the cookie-cutter repository, I get the following linter warning
[{
    "resource": "/c:/source_code/electroroute_code/python_cookiecutter/{{cookiecutter.app_name}}/Dockerfile",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#3",
    "code": "26",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "invalid reference format",
    "source": "dockerfile-utils",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 13,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 49
}]

The linter warning disappears when I disable the Docker extension.
I want to include the Docker extension in VS Code. I also want to disable this linter warning for the cookie-cutter repository, without impacting the Docker linter warnings for the feature repositories.
I have tried adding the following code to the .vscode/settings.json file in the repository but it made no difference.
{
    "docker.languageserver.lintingRules": {
        "26": "ignore"
    }
}

I have also tried creating a hadolint.yaml file at the root of the repository to ignore the problem rule but that made no difference. The hadolint.yaml file contained
ignored:
- DL3006

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please try adding using the # dockerfile-utils: ignore comment to ignore issues from dockerfile-utils. This was introduced into the VS Code extension last year so this feature should be available to you.
# dockerfile-utils: ignore
FROM python:{{cookiecutter.python_version}}-slim

Hope it helps!

Just cross off "dockerfile" from the shell formatter language list if you have the extension 'shell-format' installed.
"shellformat.effectLanguages": [
            "shellscript",
-            "dockerfile",
            "dotenv",
            "hosts",
            "jvmoptions",
            "ignore",
            "gitignore",
            "properties",
            "spring-boot-properties",
            "azcli"
          ]


I am not using the shell-format extension @snowfox. Are you saying I should use the shell-format extension, rather than the Docker extension?

Maybe you have a different story. My issue was caused by the 'shell-format' extension. Good luck!
